# Can the C++ compiler optimize away the use of dummy variables that are used to pass the results of functions to another function?

Tags: c++, optimization

In the code snippet below:

```
A a = fxn1(x1, x2, ...);
B b = fxn2(y1, y2, ...);
C c = fxn3(a, b);
```

Can the creation of the dummy variables 'a' and 'b' with the results of fxn1 and fxn2 be optimized away by the compiler so that the results of fxn1 and fxn2 are passed directly as arguments to fxn3?

I realize that the code could easily be written as

```
C c = fxn3(fxn1(x1, x2, ...), fxn2(y1, y2, ...));
```

to accomplish the same intent. However, IMO this would become very clunky if more arguments are involved and there are more dependencies between functions.

I am aware of the lazy evaluation approach but that would involve more code than I would like to introduce. Thx

Comment: Perhaps. It kind of depends on the functions and on what `A` and `B` are, and what optimizations you enabled when building. Check the generated machine code if you're curious to see what the compiler does.

Comment: Be aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)

Comment: How would you tell, by looking at the assembly code or by any other means, whether a variable has been optimised away?

Comment: Here's a short demo: https://godbolt.org/z/NSTqw7 Unless you do something complicated with `C c`, even that gets optimized away.

Comment: @Blaze. Thx for the example. Seeing the assembly makes it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply doing it?
The following code:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C { int c; };

A fxn1( int x1, int x2 )
{   
    return A{ x1+x2 };
}

B fxn2( int y1, int y2 )
{
    return B{ y1-y2 };
}   

C fxn3( const A& a, const B& b ) 
{   
    return C{ a.a * b.b };
}

int main()
{   
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 2;
    int y1 = 3;
    int y2 = 4;
    A a = fxn1(x1, x2);
    B b = fxn2(y1, y2);
    C c = fxn3(a, b); 

    std::cout << c.c << std::endl;
}
```

Results to:

```
0000000000400630 <main>:
  400630:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400634:   be fd ff ff ff          mov    $0xfffffffd,%esi
  400639:   bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  40063e:   e8 cd ff ff ff          callq  400610 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)@plt>
  400643:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400646:   e8 95 ff ff ff          callq  4005e0 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@plt>
  40064b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40064d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400651:   c3                      retq   
  400652:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400656:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40065d:   00 00 00
```

What you see is:

All your functions are reduced to a single constant load:

```
400634:   be fd ff ff ff          mov    $0xfffffffd,%esi
```

Which is simply "-3".

The rest of main is only for using `std::cout`.

So your question:

> Can the creation of the dummy variables 'a' and 'b' with the results of fxn1 and fxn2 be optimized away by the compiler so that the results of fxn1 and fxn2 are passed directly as arguments to fxn3?

Is simply "YES" :-) It "can" be but it is not a must. Especially if your code depends on more variables and produces side effects, it will maybe not evaluated to a const var. So you have always to measure and check it out for your own real code!

Comment: "*Why not simply doing it?*" Because that proves nothing. Give those types destructors and I suspect you'll find something quite different.

Comment: Exactly! So you simply have to check!

Comment: The question was not about what compilers do. It was about what compilers *can do*.

Comment: Exactly! And as you see: They CAN optimize all the things away but it is never a guarantee!

Comment: Yes. I see the difference now with Compiler Explorer. Thx

Comment: Done :). Although I would also like to add that the answers from bruno and JVApen also help to provide further understanding as to what's going on behind the code.

Comment: @neophyte: Thanks! Yes, that is what we have the upvotes for :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

In theory, yes, it is possible. If you write the one-liners, you also get temporaries that are modeled by the compiler.
The difference in intend sits in the lifetime and the destructor. When your compiler can prove the lifetime doesn't matter, it can do so.

In practice, you'll need to ensure the compiler can see what's going on, either be enabling link time optimization (LTO) or by having the code inlined.
Having custom destructors in the classes A and B or one of its members doesn't help, especially when in another CPP file (if you don't have LTO)

One can wonder if it even makes sense to worry about these elements. Often it makes more sense to profile your code and look at where you loose the most time.

When it does seem to be part of the hot path, check the generated assembly. Compiler explorer is a very good online tool to help you with that.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder why my question got downvoted. C++ is such a broad and deep subject that I don't think a lot of those new to C++ would know this answer.

Comment: It wasn't me, though, looking at the question, my first reaction was: Why do you even care? Do you see a performance problem at that place? And does reordering the Dtors improve memory/cpu usage?

Comment: It may or may not be useful but knowing what goes on under the hood helps to increase understanding. Seeing the generated assembly helped to clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

> I realize that the code could easily be written as

warning, with

> ```
> A a = fxn1(x1, x2, ...);
> B b = fxn2(y1, y2, ...);
> C c = fxn3(a, b);
> ```

you are sure *fxn1(x1, x2, ...)* is executed before *fxn2(y1, y2, ...)*, but with `C c = fxn3(fxn1(x1, x2, ...), fxn2(y1, y2, ...));` the order of the execution of the two arguments is indeterminate (if I am not wrong)

So these two forms aren't equivalent except if there is no side effect at all, including in the management of the returned values in case their are instances of classes

> Can the creation of the dummy variables 'a' and 'b' with the results of fxn1 and fxn2 be optimized away by the compiler so that the results of *fxn1* and *fxn2* are passed directly as arguments to *fxn3* ?

If the local variables *a* and *b* are only used to b the arguments of *fxn3* yes perhaps, but respecting the order of call of  *fxn1* and *fxn2* except if it can know there are no side effect at all, may be also these calls are replaced by their code (managed as inline) etc